How to replace 0 with None in a pandas column?
This seems to be a trivial question but for some reason, I cannot get the code to work.
Firstly for the context, column[B] is an object data typed column with 0, "A", "B".



A
B





0



0



A



B



I do not want any 0 in the column so I tried the following.
df['A'] = pd.Series(position).map({ 0: np.nan}) 
df['A'] = np.where(df['B'] ==0, np.nan, 1)
df['A'] = df['B'].replace(0, np.nan)
df['A'] = df['B'].replace(0, None)
df['A'] = df['B'].replace(np.nan, None)
df['A'] = df['B'].astype(object).replace('0', None)

After I save the dataframe to excel using df.to_excel("ABC.xlsx"), the 0 will remain in column ["A"]. Same thing when I run print(df["A"]). Am I missing anything?

If that's the case, then you have a non-reproducible issue. It said you are not understanding your problem. We cannot answer your question because your problem is not reproducible. Create a reproducible example and check result.

Creating another reproducible example to verify means creating a new example that you think is similar to your situation, running your code, and checking the results. For example, try running the following code and check the output to see what column A of df looks like, and also check it in the file 1234.xlsx:
import pandas as pd;df = pd.DataFrame({'B':[0, 'A', 'B']});df['A'] = df['B'].replace(0, None);print(df);df.to_excel('1234.xlsx')

No. The value is numerical 0. I manage to sort of resolve it by using np.where(df['A']==0, None,df['A']) at the later stage of code. For some reason when I debug, found out that after another line of code that call upon that column ....df["C"] = np.where(df["A"] =="A", True, df["C"]), it convert all the None value to 0.

I understand you want to replace the value 0 in column 'B' with NaN (None) in column 'A'. However, the issue might be arising because the value 0 in column 'B' is of type integer, whereas you are trying to replace it with NaN, which is of type float.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 0, 'A', 'B']})

# Replace 0 with NaN in column 'A'
df['A'] = df['B'].replace(0, np.nan)

# Print DataFrame to check
print(df)

# Save DataFrame to Excel
df.to_excel("ABC.xlsx", index=False)


